# Check if element is first or third in rows of 3 elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i have multiple rows of DIVs and each row has 3 elements, how to check if the element is the first in the row or the third in the row? For example:

```
<div>1</div> <div>2</div> <div>3</div>
<div>4</div> <div>5</div> <div>6</div>
<div>7</div> <div>8</div> <div>9</div>
<div>10</div> <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
```

So how to check if element is 1,4,7,10 or if it is 3,6,9,12 using jquery or javascript?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot see any "row" in your code, only indentation

Comment: And how are you positioning these elements? Will the text always reflect the element's position in the order?

Comment: Do you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/Rz2Qt/

Comment: I need a solution that hopefully checks mathematically this numbers like the native :odd and :even selectors but these won't work in my case. The first and third element in each row will get off screen when the resolution is low as they are absoltely position...so want to change position of these depending on user's resolution

Comment: You could use CSS with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for the resolution and maybe the [`nth-child` selector](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-child) to select every third element.

Comment: What do you mean you want to check the element? Do you want to loop through all of these <div>s once and figure it out? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/STMH7/1/  Or do you want a function that takes in an element and will tell you its position?

Comment: yup @skykine3000 your solution is correct..that's it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using container's class=".cont", the following will alert "First or Third" on div click:

```
$('.cont div').click(function(){
    var divIndex = $(this).index('.cont div');
    if(((divIndex % 3) == 2) || ((divIndex % 3) == 0))
        alert('First or Third');
});
```

Comment: this won't work as it will select elements in the middle as well..so if i select even, it will select element with text 1,3,5 and so on..5 is in the middle position so i don't want to select this

Comment: oh sorry misunderstood this...i already know this solution but i want to do it without giving a special class to the elements that's the trick

Comment: It is assumed here that there's a wrapper for each row. I will update for when it has no wrappers - thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSamuel you can use the container's class like this: $('.container div:even'). will make the update to fit your needs

Comment: but this loops through the elements; how to make it check a single element...for example if div number 3 is at the beginning of the row, do something?

Comment: also remember each row is not wrapped into a containter...all the elements are just given a class and are wrapped in one div which has a specific width which forces the elements to wrap into a new row after each 3 elements

Comment: sorry again how to do the check if the click is on any of the actual DIVs not on the container?

Comment: yup was going to explain that `(divIndex % 3) == 1` isn't correct but you just edited it...now it works flawlessly...thanks very much for your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo:

http://jsfiddle.net/fQdHk/1/

```
(function () {
    var n = 3;
    $('div').each(function (i) {
        if(i % n === 0) $(this).css({clear:'left'});
    });
})();
```

Comment: sorry this just lists all of the elements..can't understand it

Comment: sorry i don't want to combine each 3 elements into 1 row...i want to check if element is 1,4,7,10 (first row) or 3,6,9,12 (third row)...and these number are just to indicate first, second, third, etc...i want to select the elements based on their index

Comment: I think you are getting the term column and row mixed up, the mean different things which adds confusion.